# Why google dns cloud is showing different results for gcloud dns records list and list from api?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I decide to switch my domain to google dns cloud. I was thinking that it is going to be easy to transfer all record to google and just change nameservers for my domain to point at google. But it took me a day to
accomplish that. Anyway I am facing this problem now:

when I do: `gcloud dns records --zone="zone" list` I can see domain records. But when i try to do that via python:

```
response = service.managedZones().list(project="stable-plasma-833").execute()
```

All i got is some default records when I opened domain.

When I do `gcloud dns changes --zone="zone" get 1`
I can see all records have status "done".

Do I have to point nameservers to google and then python will show cirrect results?

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered that this mehtod for geting records was changed from:

```
response = service.managedZones().list(project="stable-plasma-833").execute()
```

to this:

```
response = service.changes().list(project="stable-plasma-833",managedZone='myzone').execute()
```

Thank you google (http://goo.rs/g4gwb).